# Unable to Login to Azure SQL Database from Tableau with email address

Tags: azure-sql-database, tableau-desktop

Something strange is occurring when trying to login to Azure SQL Database from Tableau with email address.

I was able to login a few days ago, but not today.

I create an account on the Azure SQL Database using the following:

CREATE USER [xxxxx.xxxxx@company.com] WITH PASSWORD = 'bA8F8%z^10AX'

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [xxxxx.xxxxx@company.com];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [xxxxx.xxxxx@company.com];

I was able to login no problem from the following login
[image]

Today I'm getting the error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server "company.com" requested by the login. The login failed.
Invalid username or password.
```

This is strange because I created a dummy user as follows:

```
CREATE USER Peter with PASSWORD = 'gRAnIAndoLKi@1'

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER Peter
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER Peter
```

I don't have any problems logging in with the user Peter. Therefore, it leads me to think that Tableau has as issue with logging in with email addresses..

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have tested this a number of times now, and it would appear Tableau has an issue with email address. For example if attempt to access Azure SQL Database after creating the user tony@hotmail.com with the following ```CREATE USER [tony@hotmail.com] with PASSWORD = 'xxxxx'``` I get the invalid error message above. However, when I create a user with an email address e.g. ```CREATE USER [tony] with PASSWORD = 'xxxxxx'``` No problems. This is weird. Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] [SQL Server] Cannot open server "company.com" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Invalid username or password.

***Cause:***

In Azure login, after @ symbol it is considering as server name is provided. Company.com is a portion of your user's name that is supplied after the @ symbol, therefore it will initially speak to the gateway that is resolved from your server's name and ask for the information of Company.com.

***Resolution:***

Add the `@myserver` to the end of the `username`, **`user@Company.com@yourservername`**.

Comment: Hi PratikLad, thanks for reaching out. What you suggested makes sense, but I don't understand how I was able to acccess the server without any issues just two days ago?